# Selecting only specific columns using IQueryable in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm kinda new to asp.net mvc. I'm currently working with code that has been developed by another person and have come to a dead end.

```
IQueryable<DatatableTrainingHistory> trainingView = (from b in db.DatatableTrainingHistorys
                                                     select b);

/* Returns the format needed to output DataTable extension */
return DataTablesResult.Create(trainingView, dataTableParam, uv => new
{
      //stuff runs here
});
```

What this code does is it selects data from all columns in a table. What I currently need is for the code to select specific columns, let's say `TrainingName`, `TrainingTime`, `Location`, and `Quota`. The output must be an `IQueryable` type since the code uses [this](https://github.com/mcintyre321/mvc.jquery.datatables) extension to output the data.

I have tried numerous ways to try to solve this.

(1)

```
IQueryable<DatatableTrainingHistory> trainingView = (from b in db.DatatableTrainingHistorys
                                                    select new DatatableTrainingHistory
                                                    {
                                                        TrainingName = b.TrainingName,
                                                        TrainingTime = b.TrainingTime,
                                                        Quota = b.Quota,
                                                        Location = b.Location,
                                                    });
```

The code above outputs an error:

```
The entity or complex type 'AppModel.DatatableTrainingHistory' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

(2)

```
IQueryable<DatatableTrainingHistory> trainingView = (from b in db.DatatableTrainingHistorys
                                                    select new
                                                    {
                                                        TrainingName = b.TrainingName,
                                                        TrainingTime = b.TrainingTime,
                                                        Quota = b.Quota,
                                                        Location = b.Location,
                                                    }).AsQueryable();
```

The code above shows an error saying:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Project.Models.DatatableTrainingHistory>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can anyone kindly point me to the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(1). `DatatableTrainingHistory` is an entity object and you simply cannot use entity object in LINQ query.

(2). You're returning `anonymous object`, so you should use `var` for it

```
var trainingView = (from b in db.DatatableTrainingHistorys
                                                    select new
                                                    {
                                                        TrainingName = b.TrainingName,
                                                        TrainingTime = b.TrainingTime,
                                                        Quota = b.Quota,
                                                        Location = b.Location,
                                                    }).AsQueryable();
```

There're two possible solutions for this:

- use anonymous object (as point (2) in your question)
- introduce new data transfer object

both of them has **pros** and **cons**, the second solution requires more efforts, but it will give you strongly type => less errors. There're couple of libraries to do the object mapping automatically for you (for example: `AutoMapper`), maybe you can try them out.

Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the type to var still gives me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Project.Models.DatatableTrainingHistory>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. I'll try to read more on DTO's.

Comment: @BaskoroS. I think the exception is being thrown some where else, your code looks completely fine (I tested)